# How to handle errors in express 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Lets say i have these routes in Express:

```
router.route('/bears/:bear_id')

    .get(function(req, res) {
        // Get the requested bear 
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                // Show the bear
            }
    })

    .put(function(req, res) {
        // Get the requested bear 
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                // Update/Create the bear
            }
    })

    .delete(function(req, res) {
        // Delete the bear
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                // Deletion successful
            }
    });
```

In this example i handle my errors with a `res.send()`. But i have read that the **right** way to handle errors is with a middleware...

**Q) How** could this be implemented in the code above??... and **why** is it better than just sending the `err` object, or `err.message`?

Comment: There is [this great article](http://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors) from Joyent about error handling in node.js. It's long, but worth checking out.

Comment: I tried to read this article, but I think it's to complex...